# Stopping ongoing app updates

Tags: wi-fi, updates

How do I force an abort on ongoing app updates happening on my Sony Xperia Aqua Android mobile? It is slowing down all other processes. My cell is setup to do updates when it finds a wifi connection, so I can turn wifi off, but I need it for the other things. Wish there was a way I could put the update downloads on hold and then resume after I'm done using the wifi.

Answer (score 2):

Few solutions:

- Open Google Play Store. Goto Settings -> Auto-update apps, then select "Don't auto-update apps". (But Google Play Services and Google Play Store will be updated regardless of this settings).
- You can install a firewall and block Google Play Services, Download, Download Manager and Google Play Store to block updates. Unblock them when you need to update apps.